# Rails - paginate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is this how will_paginate is used? The example in their documentation doesn't demonstrate result of a sql query. 
I installed included the gem in the gem file, restarted without any errors. but still not working.

```
def list_items
        @list = Item.find(:all, :select => 'status', :conditions => { :status => ["New"]} )
        @list_page = @list.paginate(:per_page => 10)
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :partial => 'item_list'}
        format.js
        end
        end

NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x97bd3fc>):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility

You need to add `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Comment: That solved the error, but still doesn't pagination. How does this render the page numbers on the view?

Comment: Does your view have `<%= will_paginate @list_page %>`?  Perhaps the require is needed on the view erb as well.

Comment: Thanks Ron. ya, I managed to render the view. It does ask for `page` parameter in the url. But running into another issue, it doesn't render the list and my stuff is ajax, and this thing is making ajax request.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that your AJAX updates the <div> that houses your pager.  Not sure if the will_paginate gem will update like that, but I know the kaminari gem will. https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commit/7110f95cde40089e6341dcea4e0ff3c3ca88b27f